# How can I use derived tables with laravel’s query builder and scopes?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

A package I’m using adds a trait to models to allow you to query for nearby places using latitude and longitude values stored in the model and a given latitude/longitude point. It does this by defining a query scope within the trait.

However, the resulting query only works with MySQL. I want to change this to use the more generic idea of derived tables. I know the following query works:

```
select *
from (
    select *, 
        (3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( places.lat ) ) 
        * cos( radians( places.lng ) - radians($lng) ) 
        + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( places.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    from (
        select *
        from places
        where places.lat between $minLat and $maxLat
        and places.lng between $minLng and $maxLng
    ) as places 
    where places.deleted_at is null 
) sub
where distance <= $1 
order by distance asc
```

where obviously `$lng` and `$lat` are values passed into the query scope’s method and the min and max values are worked out from these.

Any attempt I’ve made at this has been based on one big `DB::raw()` inside a `$query->select()`, but I can’t get the where deleted_at in the right place or a `from places` get’s tacked on at the end.

Does anyone have experience of using derived tables with Laravel’s query builder.

*EDIT:* The closest I’ve got it the following:

```
$distanceQuery = DB::table(DB::raw("(
    select *
    from {$this->getTable()}
    where $latColumn between $minLat and $maxLat
    and $lngColumn between $minLng and $maxLng
) as places"))
    ->select(DB::raw("*,
        (
            $meanRadius * acos(cos(radians($lat)) * cos (radians($latColumn))
            * cos (radians($lngColumn) - radians($lng))
            + sin(radians($lat)) * sin (radians($latColumn)))
        ) as distance"))
    ->toSql();
return DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $distanceQuery . ') as sub'))
    ->select(DB::raw("*"))
    ->where('distance', '<=', $distance)
    ->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
```

But this doesn’t include the where deleted_at is null constraint which Laravel normally automatically add.